# MCU with single external clock pin

Tags: oscillator

I am selecting an MCU [(EFM8BB10F2G-A-QFN20 Datasheet here)](http://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm8bb1-datasheet.pdf) for one of my projects and I found a strange thing. This MCU has only pin for external clock source:

[image: pin config]

Till now, I have never encountered this case. In every other MCU I have used, there were two pins for connecting an external crystal. How can I use a crystal in this case?

Comment: While not the case here, there are in fact oscillator circuit topologies which ground one side of the crystal.  It's rather rare to use these for an on-chip clock oscillator, but I did once work with such a part - only cannot recall what it specifically was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (directly). The datasheet clearly states on the first page:

> Clock Sources:
>
> • Internal 24.5 MHz oscillator with ±2% accuracy
>
> • Internal 80 kHz low-frequency oscillator
>
> • External CMOS clock option

What you can use is a crystal oscillator (ie. crystal + active circuitry in the same component).

Comment: Supplementary answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217320/where-are-the-external-oscillator-pins-on-pic12lf1572